# Changing background image from appDelegate in ios app

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, ios7

In my iOS 6/7 app, non Storyboard, I set a background image in my appDelegate.  All my views have transparent backgrounds so the background image shows thru.  This works well except I want to change the image on rotation.  I'd like to have a portrait and landscape background image.
I've tried to reset the background image in the view with a call to my appDelegate and change the image on rotation.  The call gets made but the image doesn't change. The code below is in my appDelegate.

```
    //  This will return the total screen height
    CGRect screen = [[Utility getUtility] getScreenFrameForCurrentOrientation];

    if(screen.size.width == 320 && screen.size.height == 480) //  Portrait iPhone4
    {
        self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_320x480.png"]];
    }
    else if(screen.size.width == 320 && screen.size.height == 568) //  Portrait iPhone5
    {
        self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_320x568.png"]];
    }
    else if(screen.size.width == 480 && screen.size.height == 320) //  Landscape iPhone 4
    {
        self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_320x480_landscape.png"]];
    }
    else if(screen.size.width == 568 && screen.size.height == 320) //  Landscape iPhone 5
    {
        self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_320x568_landscape.png"]];
    }
```

I called this from the view didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation and viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear but the image doesn't change.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: I see--- you step through the code and it does what you want, but the graphics don't change.  Got it.

Comment: How about your object self in above code! Is it same as the one you want to change image!!

Comment: Yes.  It is the same "self" as was used to set the background image in the first place.  I'm making a call into the appDelegate to try to reset the background image from there.